# Accept circles on migration stats pages are too low

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, migration, 10k-tools

There are a couple of different styles of showing accepts on sites. One of those styles, circles around the numbers, seems to be slightly broken on the mod tools pages, specifically the [migration history page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=today).

[image: Accept circles are low on Seasoned Advice]

I only have access to this page on two sites with circles for accepts, Seasoned Advice and English Language Learners but it exists on both of them and on both the "here" and "away" pages.

The other accepts marker - the squares - encompasses the word "answers" rather than excluding them so they don't seem to be a problem on this page.

Comment: [same on Graphic Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I2YK.png)

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (perhaps with the roll-out of [responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/295232)). The circles have been replaced with filled boxes:

[image]

([source, 10k only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=last30days))